# When did Galilee become part of Iudaea? When did it become separate?

Tags: roman-empire, jews, 1st-century

According to Wikipedia, Galilee "briefly became a part of it[i.e. Iudaea province], then separated from it for two to three centuries". When did these two events happen? Sources encouraged.

Answer (score 4):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judea_(Roman_province)#Judea_as_Roman_province.28s.29), after the death of King Herod Agrippa in 44CE Galilee and Peraea were incorporated into the province of Iudaea.

Over the next century there were no less than [3 major Jewish revolts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_wars). The last one was such a serious blow to Roman prestige that when Emperor Hadrian finally suppressed it, he decided the best way to prevent any further recurrence was [genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_wars#Aftermath). Judiaisim was outlawed, the province and its Jewish name were wiped from the map, and its territory combined with Syria into Syria Palestina. In 193 Syria-Coele and Syria Phoenice were split from that. Its tough to tell on the rough maps I have access to, but it looks like the latter of the two new territories contained Galilee (or at least parts of it).

[image]

Comment: The Romans even resurrected the memory of the long gone Philistines - hence Palestina.